# Android - Inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

**Error Details**

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: \u003citem\u003e inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.","sources":[{"file":"...\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\ids.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":57,"endColumn":61,"endOffset":114}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details.
```

**Resource File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tv_deviceName" type="id">tv_deviceName</item>
</resources>
```

**Build Environment**

- Android Studio 3.1.4
- minSdkVersion = 21
- targetSdkVersion = 28
- compileSdkVersion = 28
- buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"

Comment: Same here in my case then i delete code from ids.xml file .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfM6Y.png)

Comment: my code looks like this - <item name="textinput_suffix_text" type="id"/> AndI'm having the same error.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When declaring id in resources, the body should be empty

```
<item
    type="id"
    name="id_name" />
```

For more info please have a look on below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id

So as **Oliver Manyasa** mentioned, it should be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tv_deviceName" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: I know this,bug if xml file in a aar file,how to fix this problem

Comment: @yuchangfu you can override the resource in your file to fix this problem.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar issue after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2.1

The error was pointing to this item in ids.xml file

```
<item name="mnuActivate" type="id">Activation</item>
```

As mentioned by the user **Sangeet Suresh**, I changed it to

```
<item name="mnuActivate" type="id" />
```

That fixed the issue.

Comment: How did you edit the file? It´s regenerated automatically

Comment: Very confusing, android studio created this automatically.

Answer (score 11):

To all others who are still scratching their head to get the solution for this is create `ids.xml` inside `src/main/res/values` with contents similar to the following (but make sure to update it with the ids you're seeing errors for):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<items>
    <item name="animator" type="id"/>
    <item name="date_picker_day" type="id"/>
    <string name="deleted_key"/>
</items>
```

Now Android Studio will be giving you an error for explicit values and if those values are coming from some library you are using then you can't make a change in the intermediate file so instead change here and while merging your code Android studio takes care of it.

Comment: Great solution! Just override these values, items, strings etc. in your own resources!

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a little giving an example ids.xml file?  I tried what you suggested but the same items are coming up in the errors after a rebuild?

Answer (score 6):

On your Resource File remove the closing tag plus the Body i.e Remove "tv_deviceName"

and let your resource file be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tv_deviceName" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Oliver Manyasa, would you share your email address or send an email to pchidzalo@must.ac.mw asap

Answer (score 3):

I had below error

```
error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

In my case I created new test project and deleted the toolbar and fab from activity_main.xml file but these were also in ids.xml file. After deleting both ids from ids.xml file I was able to run. In your ids.xml file you may have lots of ID's but as I created a new project So, It has No IDs.

[image]

In above screenshot you can see the exact file location.

Comment: And finally my project doesn't have a single line of code.

Comment: @young Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

For me this was actually failing because the new gradle versions. I am pretty sure that some plugins I'm using have incompatibilities with newest gradle. I ended up with success build having the following versions:

gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle file

```
 dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
 }
```

EDIT:

As we want to use 3.2.+ versions now, that isn't a reliable solution.

What I ended up doing is creating a new ids.xml file, and overriding all the values that have been conflicting.

ids.xml file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <item name="cc_card" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_ccv" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_entry" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_entry_internal" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_exp" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_form_layout" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_four_digits" type="id"/>
        <item name="cc_zip" type="id"/>
        <item name="text_helper" type="id"/>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply created this auto-generated file in `res/xml/values` with empty tags like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <item type="id" name="icon" />
    ...
</resources>
```

That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

In the the `values` folder I double clicked the `ids.xml` file this was causing the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="roll_button" type="id">rollButton</item>
</resources>
```

[image]

I tried the some of the voted answers:

```
<item name="roll_button" type="id">
```

But I got an error that said:

```
The element type "item" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</item>".
```

So to fix I just added the matching ending tag:

```
<item name="roll_button" type="id"></item>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm new to `Kotlin` so what I just noticed and what I didn't realize is the `<item name="roll_button" type="id" />` needs the **forward slash** at the end to go before the closing `>`. If you don't include it then you will get the error I got but if you do include it t**he accepted answer works**.