# Android resource compilation failed after the update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After the updating the android studio... my project is crashed with the error below

```
    Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1668: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1669: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1670: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1671: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1672: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1673: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1674: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1700: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\aliya\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\c7465495da03cdfc80a78f27c03646df\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\aliya\Desktop\EventsToday\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

My Project level gradle is

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
      //  maven {
        //    url 'https://maven.google.com'
       // }
       // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.1"
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
            }
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app level gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "waleed.com.eventstoday"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                buildConfigField "String", "baseUrl", '"www.google.com"'
                buildConfigField "String", "buildName", '"Development"'
                buildConfigField "String", "countryCode", '"+92"'
            }
            release {
                buildConfigField "String", "baseUrl", '"www.google.com"'
                buildConfigField "String", "buildName", '"Release"'
                buildConfigField "String", "countryCode", '"+92"'
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.6'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'
    implementation 'io.smooch:core:5.12.1'
    implementation 'io.smooch:ui:5.12.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please do tell if there is any more information required. Any help will be appreciated. After the update its not working have also tried to downgrade the gradle to 3.1.0 but it did not work
Just opened the values.xml in build->intermediates->incremental->mergeDebugResources->merge.dir->values->values.xml i have errors

> urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 showing URI is not registered
>
> " xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools" showing URI is not registered

Comment: Please check the following link. I hope it helps :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty)

Comment: Did you try to clean and build?

Comment: @KyloRen i have checked and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @MidasLefko  yeah i have tried to clean and build it again but nothing happend !

Answer (score 9):

search for **type="id"** in whole project, then for every instance remove **item tag contents**, for example:

change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id">2468</item>
</resources>
```

to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: it was gradle version problem i was using 3.2.0 ... but the libraries didn't support so i have to degrade the version to 3.1.4 and its working fine now .. By the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

In your project, go through all of the `src/main/res/values/<name>.xml` files and look for constructs like:

```
<item type="id" name="my_id">some random value here</item>
```

The thing is IDs can either have no value (creates a new ID) or refer to other IDs (using `@id/other_id` syntax in the value field). Just remove the values to match:

```
<item type="id" name="my_id"></item>
```

or

```
<item type="id" name="my_id"/>
```

Comment: it was gradle version problem i was using 3.2.0 ... but the libraries didn't support so i have to degrade the version to 3.1.4 and its working fine now .. By the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

it was gradle version problem i was using 3.2.0 ... but the libraries didn't support so i have to degrade the version to 3.1.4 and its working fine now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25557392)

Comment: @veben it was my own question and i have answered it. So it might help others kindly accept it as answer. Thanks