# Error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I can't compile my project after upgrading Gradle to version 4.
Android Studio throws an error:

> Android resource compilation failed
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1475: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1477: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1478: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1479: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1480: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1481: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1482: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1483: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1493: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grow_director_v2_net\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1714: warn: ignoring element 'g' with unknown namespace 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'.

By this link a have these properties:

```
 <item name="animator" type="id">false</item>
 <item name="date_picker_day" type="id">false</item>
 <item name="date_picker_header" type="id">false</item>
 <item name="date_picker_month_and_day" type="id">false</item>
 <item name="day_picker_selected_date_layout" type="id">false</item>
 <item name="month_text_view" type="id">false</item>
```

I didn't set all of these properties.

I've already seen these issues:

- [Android - Inner element must either be a resource reference or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty)
- [Android resource compilation failed after the update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518892/android-resource-compilation-failed-after-the-update)

compileSdkVersion 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'

Comment: It looks like some library you're importing has a bad set of definitions in its `ids.xml` resource file. Are you using any date picker libraries?

Comment: @BenP.
Yes, I thought about this too.  In project included library [MaterialDateTimePicker] (https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).  And I even created an issue there - https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues
But I commented this library in gradle, and this error didn't disappear.

Comment: @PonomarenkoOleh Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Amrut I'm waiting of fixing the issue: https://github.com/Shusshu/Android-RecurrencePicker/issues/17#issuecomment-428330873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project includes a library "Android-RecurrencePicker" that is not adapted for Android Studio 3.2.0. 
There is an issue to the author for updating his library - https://github.com/Shusshu/Android-RecurrencePicker/issues/17#issuecomment-428330873.

Eventually, the solution was to download this 3d party library to project and include in a project locally. After this, I changed dependencies and refactored code of this library manually.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error after updating my IDE. I was able to resolve it by adding it to string resource.

first: I change this

> `<item name="animator" type="id">false</item>`

to

> `<item name="animator_false" type="id"/>`

Secondly: I Added

> `<string name="animator_false">false</string>`

to strings.xml.
The problem solved.

Comment: <item name="animator" type="id">false</item>
I don't have this row in my code, this row is from library "Android-RecurrencePicker". I can't change it myself.

Comment: Check all the files you have in the res/values directory, you will see the file that has the content of the displayed error. Then follow the steps above. In my case, I saw it in an ids.xml file, I followed the steps and it works.