# Android build error not showing R content

Tags: android, build

So I just transferred my app to another laptop and when I tried to build this error prompted. please help. What do I need to change?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:651: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
  C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:652: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

  Command: C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\f919f683d074912d6e0f1b8bf0931ab0\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:4:5-54: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

  C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:3:5-47: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

  Command: C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\f919f683d074912d6e0f1b8bf0931ab0\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Users\Rhylle Vincent\Desktop\01-03-2018-740pm\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

ids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="timebar" type="id">Time</item>
    <item name="textClock" type="id">textClock</item>
</resources>
```

Comment: something wrong in your values.xml please share that file

Comment: i have no values.xml sir, where can I look for it?

Comment: @Kristopher - Do you have any resource files? If so, you might have an error due to the resource body tag not being empty. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty) solution.

Comment: please post \app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml

Comment: Hey did you updated your android studio ?

Comment: have a look over this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484967/6672577

Comment: There is an error in `app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml`, please add the content of this file.

Comment: there is the ids.xml sirs, do i need to delete those?

Comment: share your values.xml file..

Comment: but my values.xml file has 3000 lines of codes

Comment: Problem solved sirs! Cheerio thank you so much! I deleted the recent file and re unzipped my downloaded folder! worked!

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="timebar" type="id"/>
    <item name="textClock" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

the ref is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id).

Answer (score 1):

On your Resource File remove the closing tag plus the Body i.e Remove "tv_deviceName"

```
  <item type="id" name="button_ok">tv_deviceName</item>
```

Id should be like this as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="button_ok" />
    <item type="id" name="dialog_exit" />
</resources>
```

Then, this layout snippet uses the "button_ok" ID for a Button widget:

```
<Button android:id="@id/button_ok"
    .... />
```

Notice that the android:id value does not include the plus sign in the ID reference, because the ID already exists, as defined in the ids.xml example above. (When you specify an ID to an XML resource using the plus sign—in the format android:id="@+id/name"—it means that the "name" ID does not exist and should be created.)

As another example, the following code snippet uses the "dialog_exit" ID as a unique identifier for a dialog:

```
showDialog(R.id.dialog_exit);
```

Refrence: [Click here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#java)