# why iI getting the same error every time i try to run my android studio application?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradle

I have deployed my website and now I'm trying to convert it into an android studio application, but whenever I try to do run my application I'm getting the same problem which is ExecuteTaskAction:
also i have tried many solutions such as invalidate cashes and restart, also adding some code lines to my program, but all of them did not work!

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2195: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:3:5-51: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2195: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:3:5-51: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:324)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2195: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:3:5-51: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteCompileException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:55)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2195: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc31501932c6f3f8a6a19a67460ffe7b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:142)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring `id` in resources, the body should be empty

```
<item type="id" name="id_name" />
```

But it seems you have a `<item>` with id that body is not empty.

Comment: I think you've nailed it.  Here's the relevant part of the OP's error stack: `Output:  C:\Users\yamanalkahwaji\AndroidStudioProjects\bloodbankproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2195: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.`  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty

Comment: hey, thank u for helping me, but ur way does not work for me, it still gives me the same error

Comment: W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.yamanalkahwaji.bloodbankproject-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.yamanalkahwaji.bloodbankproject-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status