# Android resource compilation failed for build/intermediates/incremental after updating android studio to 3.3.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I used NDK and everything was successfully working but once I changed my system everything became hell and not able to start build/ run project - I am getting below errors

```
Android resource compilation failed
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:624: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:625: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:626: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:627: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:628: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:629: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:630: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:631: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:637: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:808: warn: ignoring element 'g' with unknown namespace 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'.
/home/bajrang/Android Live Projects/Parkway/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergePentestDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

I have done deleting **.gradle** folder and **cleaning**, **rebuilding**, deleting build folder but no success, please help me -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Inner element must either be a resource reference or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076491/android-inner-element-must-either-be-a-resource-reference-or-empty)

Answer (score 0):

I was using below line in project's ids.xml file

```
<item type="id" name="day_picker_selected_date_layout">false</item>
```

after changing it to below line it is fixed.

```
<item type="id" name="day_picker_selected_date_layout"/>
```